# Introduction to Mathematical Model of a Population Growth

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have started learning Differential Equations from my Textbook **"Differential Equations with Boundary-Value Problems"** by Dennis G. Zill, 7th Ed.

On the introductory chapter, there is this benign exercise:
[image]

Nevertheless, despite my efforts, I cannot seem to understand the Answer from the Instructor's Manual. The answer goes as such:

> At t=0, $dP/dt=0.15P(0)+20=15+20=35$. Thus, the population is increasing at a rate of 3500 individuals per year.
> If the population is 500 at time $t=T$ then
> $$\left.\frac{dP}{dt}\right\rvert_{t=T}=0.15P(T)+20=0.15(500)+20=95.$$
> Thus, at this time, the population is increasing at a rate of 9500 individuals per year.

Why should the population increase at rates of 3500 and 9500 individuals per year instead of 35 and 95? Or is it a mistake from the solution manual?

Comment: It appears to be a mistake in the solution manual. At first I thought that the problem might have been supposed to say that population was measured in hundreds, but that’s inconsistent with substituting $500$ for $T$ (instead of $5$) in the solution to the second question.

Comment: @billyandriam, the answers are $35$ and $95$ respectively. What's yours and the one written in the solution?

Comment: @SarGe What's written in the solution is the part which I put in the blockquotes. I found it to be 35 and 95 as well. But I don't understand why the solution suggests rates of 3500 and 9500 as well.

Comment: The question might be missing some context or as @Brian M. Scott said, the solution must be wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for  your time. I was starting to feel really confused about it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott in an E-mail, the Author of the book provided me with the following explanation: "Because the unit of population is not specified, the person who did the Solutions Manual made the (not unreasonable) assumption that 1 unit of population was 100 persons.  So you see that the solution does not depend on what the unit of population actually is."

Comment: @billyandriam: It’s true that the solution does not depend on the unit of population, but **only if one uses the same unit throughout**. The person who did the Solutions Manual failed to do so, so the solution is incorrect.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think you have a point. I also do NOT believe that one can choose any unit since the problem already stated that **P is the number of individuals in the community.** Thus, 1 unit of population equals 1 person or 1 individual.

Comment: @billyandriam: Oh, I agree that the problem statement was clear on that point. I just meant that it’s true that the formula doesn’t change: it works with any units, provided that one uses them consistently.